# Using ticks, backticks and double quotation marks in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append div with jQuery and I am already using " and '. Can I use backticks with it as I am already selecting elements within the command?

```
$(this).append("<div class='row'><div id='addQuestion' style='float:left;' class='col-sm-6'><h3 style='margin-bottom:15px;'>Submit Question</h3><form onsubmit='createQuestion(quizType, $("#submitQ").val(), $("#submitA1").val(), $("#submitA2").val(), $("#submitA3").val(), $("#submitA4").val(), $("#submitCorrect").val(), $("#submitExpl").val(), $("#submitAuthor").val(), $("#submitDesc").val(), $("#submitDate").val());return false;' method='POST'><label style='margin-right:30px;' for='add-banking-question'><input class='form-control' id='add-banking-question' type='radio' name='add-q-quizType' value='BankingQuizQuestion' checked>Investment Banking</label><label for='add-trading-question'><input class='form-control' id='add-trading-question' type='radio' name='add-q-quizType' value='TradingQuizQuestion'>Sales & Trading</label><input style='margin-top:10px;' class='form-control' type='text' id='submitQ'  placeholder='Question' name='addq-q'><input class='form-control' type='text' id='submitA1' placeholder='Answer 1' name='addq-a1'><input class='form-control' type='text' id='submitA2' placeholder='Answer 2' name='addq-a2'><input class='form-control' type='text' id='submitA3' placeholder='Answer 3' name='addq-a3'><input class='form-control' type='text' id='submitA4' placeholder='Answer 4' name='addq-a4'><input class='form-control' type='text' id='submitCorrect' placeholder='Correct answer index' name='addq-correct'><input class='form-control' type='text' id='submitDesc' placeholder='Short description' name='addq-desc'><textarea class='form-control' type='text' id='submitExpl' placeholder='Explanation' name='addq-expl'></textarea><input class='form-control' type='text' id='submitAuthor' placeholder='Your name' name='addq-author'><input class='form-control' type='text' hidden id='submitDate' name='addq-date'><input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Submit question'><div hidden id='success-submit'>Successfully submitted. Thanks!</div></form></div></div>")
```

Comment: You can use backticks so long as the browsers you're targeting support ES2016. We could give you a much better answer if you showed your *actual* code.

Comment: Please see code.

Comment: You can use `\"` and `\'` - backticks should be used for template literals.  You might find it easier to build up the string switching quote styles as required, eg:   `var html = "'" + '"';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backticks to delimit your string so long as the browsers you're aiming to support ES2016 - which most do with IE being the exception, as always.

```js
$('#foo').append(`<div class="row"><div id="addQuestion" style="float:left;" class="col-sm-6"><h3 style="margin-bottom:15px;">Submit Question</h3><form onsubmit="createQuestion(quizType, $('#submitQ').val(), $('#submitA1').val(), $('#submitA2').val(), $('#submitA3').val(), $('#submitA4').val(), $('#submitCorrect').val(), $('#submitExpl').val(), $('#submitAuthor').val(), $('#submitDesc').val(), $('#submitDate').val());return false;"method="POST"><label style="margin-right:30px;" for="add-banking-question"><input class="form-control" id="add-banking-question" type="radio" name="add-q-quizType" value="BankingQuizQuestion" checked>Investment Banking</label><label for="add-trading-question"><input class="form-control" id="add-trading-question" type="radio" name="add-q-quizType" value="TradingQuizQuestion">Sales & Trading</label><input style="margin-top:10px;" class="form-control" type="text" id="submitQ" placeholder="Question" name="addq-q"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="submitA1" placeholder="Answer 1" name="addq-a1"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="submitA2" placeholder="Answer 2" name="addq-a2"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="submitA3" placeholder="Answer 3" name="addq-a3"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="submitA4" placeholder="Answer 4" name="addq-a4"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="submitCorrect" placeholder="Correct answer index" name="addq-correct"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="submitDesc" placeholder="Short description" name="addq-desc"><textarea class="form-control" type="text" id="submitExpl" placeholder="Explanation" name="addq-expl"></textarea><input class="form-control" type="text" id="submitAuthor" placeholder="Your name" name="addq-author"><input class="form-control" type="text" hidden id="submitDate" name="addq-date"><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit question"><div hidden id="success-submit">Successfully submitted. Thanks!</div></form></div></div>`)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

If you're aiming at older browsers then you will need to escape the inner quotes using either `\'` or `\"` as appropriate.

That being said, I have several suggestions regarding your code:

Firstly, always put styling in an external stylesheet. Don't use inline `style` attributes. Similarly, use unobtrusive event handlers. Don't put `onsubmit` or any `onX` event attributes in the HTML code.

Secondly, with that much HTML code tied closely to your JS code, you're creating a potential maintenance issue in the future. I'd instead suggest having all that HTML available in the DOM when the page loads, but having it hidden by default, using either CSS or a `<template />` element. You can then `clone()` and `append()` it when needed. This de-couples the JS code and the HTML code, and it makes the JS code much more succinct.